# Large mathematical operation c++

Tags: c++, pow, largenumber

I want large mathematical operation in c++.

```
long long h= 4294967295;
long long d=7910266469;
long long n=10021211227;
long long result;
```

I am need calculate this is:

> h^d mod n

```
result=pow(h,d) % n;
```

I dont know which type using.Please help me for choose type numbers..
Thanks

Comment: I am using Dev-C++

Comment: error: result must be double type

Comment: you should do the maths first. Maybe there is a number type that allows you to do `pow(h,d)` but given that you need the result only mod `n` you dont really need `pow(h,d)`. For sure there are identities that you can use to make the calculation doable with `long long`, I just dont know them by heart ;)

Comment: @tobi303 please help for code

Comment: Don't reinvent RSA, use a crypto library ;) Or read up on the [Barrett reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrett_reduction).

Comment: What you need is *fast modular exponentiation*. Google it and you'll find a lot!

Comment: The answer is 8068405457.

Comment: I am suggesting you to find a better representation of your result **before** starting to write the code. You can for example take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)

Comment: @BaummitAugen yes right answer but I am need code

Comment: why dont your are help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).
There is a pretty nice example with the following memory-efficient pseudo code:

```
function modular_pow(base, exponent, modulus)
    if modulus = 1 then return 0 
    c := 1
    for e_prime = 1 to exponent 
        c := (c * base) mod modulus
    return c
```

There is even a example for beeing memory-efficient and using less operations. I think getting the c++ code out of it should be possible.

If you use this method, `long long` for your solution should be fine.

---

Not tested but a simple 1:1 translation from the pseudo code from above...

```
long long result = 1; 
int i;
for( i=0; i<d;i++){
    result = (result * h) % n;
}
```

Comment: This code other programming language i am bad converting to c++.

Comment: Maybe i should note that for large `d` the calculation will take really really really long